# Leaflet zoom less than default

Tags: leaflet

How can I make leaflet zoom less with mouse wheel ? If I move my mouse wheel as little as I can, it zooms like 3 levels.

Comment: Please note that if you're using Chrome *and* Windows *and* Leaflet-1.0.0-rc1, there's a bug affecting the scrollwheel zoom speed. See https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4538

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wheelPxPerZoomLevel: 150` is the option that it seems to be affecting the mouse wheel zoom "speed".

```
// @option wheelPxPerZoomLevel: Number = 50
// How many scroll pixels (as reported by [L.DomEvent.getWheelDelta](#domevent-getwheeldelta))
// mean a change of one full zoom level. Smaller values will make wheel-zooming
// faster (and vice versa).
wheelPxPerZoomLevel: 50
```

Comment: If you happen to be using mapbox.js, you'd pass it like this - `const map = L.mapbox.map(mapContainer, null, { wheelPxPerZoomLevel: 150 });` See https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.1.1/l-mapbox-map/

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an option that is not directly listed on the website documentation but the source has JsDoc lines for it...

---

`this.options.zoomDelta` is where you want to set the amount the zoom is changed by. `this` is your current `Map` object.

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/6e8ac319931da744810bef81fffbfc4adbf3a39a/src/map/Map.js#L94
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/6e8ac319931da744810bef81fffbfc4adbf3a39a/src/map/Map.js#L160

---

For mouse-wheel zooming, or pinch zooming.  Adjusting `this.options.zoomSnap` setting will make it snap or settle on levels.

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/a069c41dd7b1f6a58a47dab26be863c107d18a9f/src/map/Map.js#L95

---

Looking at the zoom controls, currently holding `Shift` and *clicking* the control zooms in by three times the current value of `map.options.zoomDelta`.  This does not seem to be true of the mouse operation.

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/a069c41dd7b1f6a58a47dab26be863c107d18a9f/src/control/Control.Zoom.js#L66

Comment: Those variables seem to only affect the zoom in/out buttons, not the mouse wheel. Just checked it.

Comment: I found the answer, I am posting an answer. `wheelPxPerZoomLevel` is what I need to change.

Comment: Sorry about that I read over the mouse wheel part.  Sorry on that!

Comment: Well, you helped me look in the right place :D